# What is a Hava Amina Teretz?

Tags: words

B"H

If "hava amina" means slightest notion, what is a hava amina teretz?

I think teretz means an answer.  So what is a slightest notion answer?

Comment: Chaya, first of all welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Second, can you tell us a little bit more about the phrase you're trying to understand? Are you sure you've parsed it correctly? Where did you come across it?

Comment: Just to refine a little bit... A _kasha_ or _kushya_ is a difficulty or attack, a _teirutz_ is a removal of the difficulty or attack. A _She'eila_ is a question and a _teshuva_ is an answer. There is a distinction between a _teirutz_ and a _teshuva_.

Comment: I think it would be hard to answer you without knowing where you heard the term "hava amina teretz" (and in what context or in what Gemara specifically)?

Answer (score 4):

Just to provide you with a quick answer that may help you, although I'm not sure it's what you're looking for, a Havah Amina is not quite as you understand it.  It is an initial assumption which the Gemara then goes on to probe to find out if it is correct.  It's like the Gemara's working hypothesis.

A Terutz (I'm using a more phonetic spelling of the word תרוץ) means an answer or a resolution to a logical challenge; at least that is how Halachik literature uses the word. Strictly speaking it means a response or justification.

I suppose a "Havah Amina Terutz" could mean an answer which someone provides to support the Havah Amina (meaning that the initial assumption was proven true under scrutiny).

Alternatively, it could mean a first attempt at a resolution, meaning a Terutz that might answer the question but has yet to be tested under scrutiny.

Either way, it sounds more like a colloquialism to me, unless you can provide a citation or tell us where you came across it.

Comment: could it be a conditional answer? a terutz which you might think answers the problem but which, under scrutiny, will/might fail?

Comment: @Dan, I suppose. Have you seen it used that way? Either way it strikes me as a colloquialism.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have...it just seems to resonate with me linguistically that way.

Comment: @Seth J,The opposite of hava amina is maskono. They can both be in a form of a kashe and a terets.

Comment: @Dan and DoubleAA, see my new edit.

Comment: Thank you all.  Seth J, your explanation was particularly helpful.

Comment: I vote for the alternative answer.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your first explanation. You mean someone had a hava amina and someone else challenged, and the response to the challenge is the hava amina terutz?

Answer (score 0):

A hava amina teretz comprises of 2 separate parts.  A hava amina & a teretz.  A hava amina is the original assumption, and the teretz is the conclusion not like the initial assumption.

For example - today is Monday because the Torah was taken out. No it is Tuesday but Rosh Chodesh.  The question what is the hava amina teretz would be asking to explain what changed or new knowledge did we get between the hava amina & the teretz

A great hava amina makes a teretz difficult, and a great teretz will pose the question so what was the  hava amina.  Discussing the hava amina teretz puts both sides into perspective at the same time, thus getting a clearer understanding of what is going on.

Other parlance could be what is the hava amina maskana, maskana being conclusion.